# Region of convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} x^s e^{-\frac{|\log(x)|}{2}}dx$ where $s \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am interested in finding the region of convergence of the integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} x^s e^{-\frac{|\log(x)|}{2}}dx
\end{align}
where $s \in \mathbb{C}.$

How do we approach this type of proablem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^s e^{-\frac12 |\log(x)|}\,dx&=\int_0^1 x^s e^{\frac12 \log(x)}\,dx+\int_1^\infty x^s e^{-\frac12 \log(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{s+1/2}\,dx+\int_1^\infty x^{s-1/2}\,dx \tag1
\end{align}$$

Then enforce the substitution $x=e^u$ in the integrals on the righ-hand side of $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you take a look at this more general question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371429/region-of-convergence-of-int-0-infty-xs-e-frac-logxk2dx-wher.   I don't this method can still be used.